# Android retrieve Json from fragment And use in another activity

Tags: android, json, list, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have a `fragment` that i use to call `url` and get `json array` then i save all data in list with `JsonModel` class

```
public class JsonModel {

private final String name;
private final String valueOne;
private final String valueTow;

public JsonModel(String name, String valueOne, String valueTow) {
    this.name = name;
    this.valueOne = valueOne;
    this.valueTow = valueTow;
}

public String getname() {
    return name;
}
public String getvalueOne() {
    return valueOne;
}
public String getvalueTow() {
    return valueTow;
}}
```

for add the data I use this code after getting the result

```
private val viewItems: MutableList<Any> = ArrayList()
.
.
.
val data = JsonModel(name, valueOne, valueTow)
viewItems.add(data)
```

how can i make this data usable in another activity
I start the new activity from the same fragment So any help for re use all this data in another activity

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data through the `putExtra` function.

```
val intent = Intent(requireContext(), YourActivity.class)
intent.putExtra("data",viewItems);
```

just add implements your model class to the Serializable interface

```
public class JsonModel implements Serializable
```

get the data from your activity

```
intent.getSerializableExtra("data") as List<JsonModel>
```

Comment: by pass the data through `putExtra` I got the error : None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.